# How to calculate extreme values for functions with three variables using derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm given the following function:

$$f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R\\ f(x,y,z) = x^3 + y^2 + z^2 + 12xy + 2z$$

I know the algorithm for calculating extreme values for functions with two variables. Does the formula $d(x,y) = rt-s^2$, where $r, t$ and $s$ are the second derivatives of the function still hold?

What is the algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to check the definiteness of the function's Hesse-matrix, see item (4) in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_definite_matrix#Characterizations